# Web-scraping in R

Tags: r

I am practicing my web scraping coding in R and I cannot pass one phase no matter what website I try.

For example,

https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/league-tables/rankings?s=Music

My goal is to extract all 77 schools' name (Oxford to London Metropolitan)

So I tried...

```
library(rvest)
url_college <- "https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/league-tables/rankings?s=Music"
college <- read_html(url_college)
info <- html_nodes(college, css = '.league-table-institution-name')
info %>% html_nodes('.league-table-institution-name') %>% html_text()
```

From F12, I could find out that all schools' name is under class '.league-table-institution-name'... and that's why I wrote that in html_nodes...

What have I done wrong?

Comment: While you're waiting for answers, you shld prbly read https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/terms-and-conditions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be running `html_nodes()` twice: first on `college`, an `xml_document` (which is correct) and then on `info`, a character vector, which is not correct.

Try this instead:

```
url_college %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('.league-table-institution-name') %>%
  html_text()
```

and then you'll need an additional step to clean up the school names; this one was suggested:

```
%>%
  str_replace_all("(^[^a-zA-Z]+)|([^a-zA-Z]+$)", "")
```

Comment: I got it... but can you please explain why we need to use OR operator | in str_replace_all("(^[^a-zA-Z]+)|([^a-zA-Z]+$)", "")? Doesn't it have to be AND operator because we are replacing both patterns with ""?

Comment: Maybe whoever suggested the edit can explain that :)